# Can't install RabbitMQ Server 3.7.1 on CentOS7 - Wrong erlang version

Tags: installation, erlang, rabbitmq, centos7

I have proper version of erlang, according to https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html.

But when I try to install rabbitmq-server-3.7.1 on my CentOS7 it says that I have wrong erlang version, and I need version >= 19.3.

But I already have 20.

What am I doing wrong?

```
test_user@test_machine: ~/Downloads
$ sudo yum install rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, versionlock
Examining rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm: rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch
Marking rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.7.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: erlang >= 19.3 for package: rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.awanti.com
 * epel: mirror.awanti.com
 * extras: mirror.awanti.com
 * updates: mirror.awanti.com
--> Processing Dependency: socat for package: rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.7.1-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: erlang >= 19.3 for package: rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch
---> Package socat.x86_64 0:1.7.3.2-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch (/rabbitmq-server-3.7.1-1.el7.noarch)
           Requires: erlang >= 19.3
           Available: erlang-R16B-03.18.el7.x86_64 (epel)
               erlang = R16B-03.18.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My erlang version:

```
test_user@test_machine: ~/Downloads
$  erl -eval 'erlang:display(erlang:system_info(otp_release)), halt().'  -noshell
"20"

test_user@test_machine: ~/Downloads
$ erl --version
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.1.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:1:1] [ds:1:1:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.1.5  (abort with ^G)
1>
```

EDITED:

That's my steps of erlang installation:
I downloaded from https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html 20.1.7 64bit version for CentOS 7
Then I ran:

```
sudo yum install esl-erlang_20.1.7-1~centos~7_amd64.rpm
```

Here is installed "*erl*" packages:

```
test_user@test_machine: ~
$ yum list installed | grep erl | grep -v perl
esl-erlang.x86_64                      20.1.7-1                        installed
```

Comment: How did you install Erlang? Can you display the Erlang package that is installed using rpm or yum?

Comment: I added additional info to the main topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a fresh CentOS 7 VM and the `esl-erlang_20.1.7-1~centos~7_amd64.rpm` rpm produces [this result](https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/ee2f4985b1f477c3d7e70a4749fe2909#file-transcript-txt). You can see that `yum` can't resolve some dependencies. I am not sure why.

The RabbitMQ team produces zero-dependency RPM files for just this reason. You should uninstall Erlang from your system, and install the package [from here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm/releases/tag/v20.1.7.1).

On my test system, the above package installs successfully followed by RabbitMQ. Complete information can be found here:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html

Comment: This did work. Don't know, what was wrong with my erlang version. Great thanks!

Comment: I'm sure the dependency issue is due to the fact that I didn't enable EPEL, which is a prerequisite for using ESL Erlang packages. Just thought I'd throw that in here for future readers.

Comment: I still couldn't understand how to do it. Anyone can share the commands, if it worked?